# Uniform continuity of the left translation operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact group.  Does the following statement hold?

Let $f\in L^\infty(G)$. The map $x\to L_xf$  is uniformly continuse map from $G$ to $L^\infty(G)$  if and only if $G$ is discrete.

Note that $L_xf(t)=f(x^{-1}t)$.

Comment: If $f$ is constant then the map is $x\mapsto L_x f$ is also constant, hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Do you mean the map $G\mapsto B(L^\infty(G))$, $x\mapsto L_x$, where $B(X)$ is the space of all bounded operators on a Banach space $X$?